# Select query using variable not running in mssql

Tags: sql-server, variables, select

Select query is not working when use variable in MSSQL2014
My Schema is :-

```
    CREATE TABLE product 
    (idproduct int, name varchar(50), description varchar(50), tax decimal(18,0))


INSERT INTO product
    (idproduct, name, description,tax)
VALUES
    (1, 'abc', 'This is abc',10),
    (2, 'xyz', 'This is xyz',20),
    (3, 'pqr', 'This is pqr',15)


CREATE TABLE product_storage 
    (idstorage int,idproduct int,added datetime, quantity int, price decimal(18,0))


INSERT INTO product_storage 
    (idstorage,idproduct, added, quantity,price)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2010-01-01,0,10.0),
    (2, 1, 2010-01-02,0,11.0),
    (3, 1, 2010-01-03,10,12.0),
    (4, 2, 2010-01-04,0,12.0),
    (5, 2, 2010-01-05,10,11.0),
(6, 2, 2010-01-06,10,13.0),
(7, 3, 2010-01-07,10,14.0),
(8, 3, 2010-01-07,10,16.0),
(9, 3, 2010-01-09,10,13.0)
```

and i am executing below command:-

```
declare @price1 varchar(10)


SELECT p.idproduct, p.name, p.tax,
[@price1]=(SELECT top 1 s.price
        FROM product_storage s
        WHERE s.idproduct=p.idproduct AND s.quantity > 0
        ORDER BY s.added ASC),
 (@price1 * (1 + tax/100)) AS [price_with_tax]
FROM product p

;
```

This is not working in MSSQL, Please Help me out.
for detail check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/91ec2/296

And My query is working in MYSQL
Check for detail :- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a71b8/1

Comment: A good example for a good question, thanks for the Fiddles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

Explanantion: You cannot use a variable "on the fly", but you can do row-by-row calculation in an APPLY...

```
SELECT p.idproduct, p.name, p.tax,
       Price.price1,
       (price1 * (1 + tax/100)) AS [price_with_tax]
FROM product p
CROSS APPLY (SELECT top 1 s.price
             FROM product_storage s
             WHERE s.idproduct=p.idproduct AND s.quantity > 0
             ORDER BY s.added ASC) AS Price(price1)

;
```

EDIT: Your Fiddle uses a bad literal date format, try this:

```
INSERT INTO product_storage 
    (idstorage,idproduct, added, quantity,price)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '20100101',0,10.0),
    (2, 1, '20100102',0,11.0),
    (3, 1, '20100103',10,12.0),
    (4, 2, '20100104',0,12.0),
    (5, 2, '20100105',10,11.0),
    (6, 2, '20100106',10,13.0),
    (7, 3, '20100107',10,14.0),
    (8, 3, '20100108',10,16.0),
    (9, 3, '20100109',10,13.0)
```

Comment: this query is also not giving the correct result of the last row, Please compare with MYSQL  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a71b8/1

Comment: AS TFroes pointed out, the reason is your thinking of sorting. SQL Server keeps no implicit row order which you could rely on. If there are more than one rows with the same value you are sorting with, it will be **totally random** which occurs first... Try both queries with unique dates and/or include the time.

Comment: Okay, But i have change the identical values, then also it shows the same result 
Check this :-http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c896a/2

Comment: @GautamChawla, Yes this was a bit odd. The reason is the way you insert the dates. Just try in your fiddle this line `select * from product_storage order by added` and explore the added column. For literal date usage read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34275965/5089204

Comment: Hi, Thanks this works fine when i convert date time. Thanks for your Help :)

Comment: As pointed in @TFroe's answer, your "order" clause is ordering by date. In your fiddle, there are two equal dates for product 3. SQL Server will order them in a random way. This can produce unpredictable results.. be careful.

Comment: @jpgrassi just some comments above you'll find the words **totally random** :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
    p.idproduct
    , p.name
    , p.tax
    , (t1.price * (1 + tax/100)) AS [price_with_tax]
FROM product p
inner join 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by s.idproduct order by s.added ASC) as linha, s.idproduct, s.price 
    FROM product_storage s
    WHERE s.quantity > 0    
) as t1
    on t1.idproduct = p.idproduct and t1.linha = 1
```

Comment: This query is also not giving the correct result of the last row, Please check with MYSQL Query

Comment: The last row (product 3) has two identical dates (2010-01-07). You need to add another condition in the query (order by)  or add time with the date. e.g. 2010-01-07 10:00:00 and 2010-01-07 15:32:00

Comment: But with the same schema it works in MYSQL
Check this :- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a71b8/1

Comment: I updated last row inserted in the product_storage with same date (2010-01-07) and the result was different.
check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/964730/1

Comment: Hi, there was a problem with the literally inserted dates in the Fiddle , think there was sort of a subtraction of int values rather than parsing a date...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct schema for SQL Server and query runs perfect as Shnugo Replied.

```
 VALUES
        (1, 1, convert(datetime,'2010-01-01'),0,10.0),
        (2, 1, convert(datetime,'2010-01-02'),0,11.0),
        (3, 1, convert(datetime,'2010-01-03'),10,12.0),
        (4, 2, convert(datetime,'2010-01-04'),0,12.0),
        (5, 2, convert(datetime,'2010-01-05'),10,11.0),
        (6, 2, convert(datetime,'2010-01-06'),10,13.0),
        (7, 3, convert(datetime,'2010-01-07'),10,14.0),
        (8, 3, convert(datetime,'2010-01-07'),10,16.0),
        (9, 3, convert(datetime,'2010-01-09'),10,13.0)
```