# Query where date = '2016/01/02' not working?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime, sql-server-2014

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b18868/1)

I have this structure of table:

```
CREATE TABLE Department
(
     [IdDepartment] int, 
     [Name] varchar(23), 
     [IdUser] int, 
     [CreateDate] datetime
);

INSERT INTO Department ([IdDepartment], [Name], [IdUser], [CreateDate])
VALUES
    (1, 'Sales', 3, '2016-01-15 17:00:00.000'),
    (2, 'Finance', null, '2016-01-13 18:00:00.000' ),
    (3, 'Accounting' , 5, '2016-03-21 22:00:00.000'),
    (4, 'IT' ,3, '2016-03-21 17:00:00.000'),
    (5, 'Secretary',null, '2016-03-21 17:00:00.000'),
    (6, 'Sport',3, '2016-02-20 16:00:00.000');
```

I want to run this query:

```
select Name 
from Department 
where CreateDate = '2016-03-21'
```

This returns 0 rows as a result.

I think it is because the date in the table structure is a datetime but I try to do this and neither works for me:

```
select Name 
from Department 
where CreateDate like '%2016-03-21%'
```

The result should be this:

```
Name
-----
Accounting
IT
Secretary
```

How can I get this result?

I hope I explained clearly, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CAST` method to compare date only not time

```
SELECT * FROM Department 
WHERE CAST(CreateDate AS DATE) ='2016-03-21'
```

Comment: @Esraa_92 Allthough - as one tiny exception! - `CAST(someCol AS DATE)` actually **is** sargable, it's worth to mention, that it still is not the best idea to do: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34052/70663

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing a `DATETIME` value against a *pure* `DATE`. You must be aware, that a `DATETIME` *includes* a time

`2016-03-21 11:00:00` is **NOT** equal to `2016-03-21`

You might compare like this

```
CAST(YourDate AS DATE)=CAST('2016-03-21' AS DATE)
```

*Hint:  As one tiny exception! - `CAST(someCol AS DATE)` actually is sargable, but it's worth to mention, that it still is not the best idea to do: dba.stackexchange.com/a/34052/70663*

or you could try a `BETWEEN`

```
YourDate BETWEEN {d'2016-03-21'} AND {ts'2016-03-21 23:59:59'}
```

or - which is the most prefered in most cases

```
YourDate >= {d'2016-03-21'} AND YourDate < {d'2016-03-22'}
```

Avoid manipulations to the column value due to [sargability](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799584/5089204)

Better avoid date literals... If you have to, you might [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34275965/5089204)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-)

Comment: @Shnugo: this man doesn't give fix, he has solution :), now in future you(@Esraa_92) will always alert

Answer (score 0):

Fully agree with @Shnugo

```
DECLARE @Department TABLE (
    IdDepartment INT,
    Name VARCHAR(23),
    IdUser INT,
    CreateDate DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO @Department
VALUES
    (1, 'Sales', 3, '2016-01-15 17:00:00'),
    (2, 'Finance', NULL, '2016-01-13 18:00:00'),
    (3, 'Accounting', 5, '2016-03-21 22:00:00'),
    (4, 'IT', 3, '2016-03-21 17:00:00'),
    (5, 'Secretary', NULL, '2016-03-21 17:00:00'),
    (6, 'Sport', 3, '2016-02-20 16:00:00')

DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '20160321' -- ISO format

SELECT Name
FROM @Department
WHERE CreateDate >= @Date
    AND CreateDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date)
```