# MS SQL setting language Globally- implications?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I had an issue to do with converting dates from strings on my database (Ms SQl Server 2008) and i found a solution using

```
EXEC sp_defaultlanguage 'username', 'british'
```

what are the dangers of changing the language from US English to British English globally on the current data and the new data?

Comment: I just added some examples to my answer, please have a look there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190303.aspx)

And try this

```
select * from sys.syslanguages
```

The language setting is very much involved in automatic formats. Especially Date-values and the calculation of weekdays can lead to differences.

The most problems you'll get with the conversion of date-literals (as you have encountered already).

I would **NOT** do this. I'd prefer to use proper formats. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34275965/5089204)

#### UPDATE

Look at these examples

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
DECLARE @d1 DECIMAL(10,2)=100.50;
SELECT FORMAT(@d1,'C')
      ,@@DATEFIRST
      ,DATEPART(WEEK,{d'2016-04-03'})
      ,FORMAT({d'2016-04-03'},'D'); 
--$100.50 | 7 | 15 |    Sunday, April 3, 2016

SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
DECLARE @d2 DECIMAL(10,2)=100.50;
SELECT FORMAT(@d2,'C')
      ,@@DATEFIRST
      ,DATEPART(WEEK,{d'2016-04-03'})
      ,FORMAT({d'2016-04-03'},'D'); 
--100,50 € |    1 | 14 |    Sonntag, 3. April 2016
```

- If you have reports depending on the week's number you would get different results.
- Any output could change...
- You might run into new exceptions when you have some code (interfaces!) where you deal with external data.
- Especially with the information given by Rahul Tripathi all this could even differ from user to user...

So once again: **Don't**

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://dbamohsin.wordpress.com/2009/11/01/sql-server-default-languages-and-misinterpretation/):

> Each SQL Server has a default language.  You can see what the default
>   language is by executing these commands (in Query Analyzer).
>
> ```
> sp_configure ‘default language’
> ```
>
> This will tell you what the default language is (sort of).  It
>   actually returns a config_value with an integer that represents the
>   language id. You can then run…
>
> ```
> sp_helplanguage
> ```
>
> You will see a list of languages that SQL Server supports.  The odd
>   thing here is that the server’s language setting will not solve your
>   problem.  This setting configures the default language for NEW users. 
>   By changing this setting, existing users will continue to have their
>   original language.  This is where it gets interesting because it’s the
>   login’s language setting that determines SQL Server’s date format. For
>   example, if user A has a default language of us_english, then a date
>   of 4/6/2006 will be interpreted as April 4, 2006.  If user B has a
>   default language of ‘British’, then the date will be interpreted as
>   June 6, 2006. The good news is that you can change the default
>   language for a user so that subsequent logins will exhibit the correct
>   interpretation of dates.  Here’s how: You can set the default language
>   for a user by issueing the following command.
>
> ```
> sp_defaultlanguage @loginame = ‘LoginName’, @language = ‘Language’
> ```
>
> After running this command, you will need to logout and back in to the
>   database in order for the change to take affect.  The good news is
>   that the language setting only needs to be done once (for each user in
>   the database).

Comment: Great, did not know about the default language being connected with the login. Upvote from my side!

Comment: that s the command I used in the question, so what are implications of setting the language globally on the user