# Convert string to DateTime in C# and write to SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to convert my string to DateTime and write it to a datetime field in my table in SQL.

```
string dateTimeString = line.Substring(5, 14);
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "dd/MM/yyyy", null).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.ODCZYTY (numer_karty,data, rodzaj,obszar,kierunek) VALUES(@numer_karty,@data, @rodzaj, @obszar, @kierunek)", conn);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numer_karty", line.Substring(0, 5));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", date);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rodzaj", line.Substring(19, 2));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@obszar", line[line.Length - 2]);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kierunek", line[line.Length - 1]);
```

`line.Substring(5, 14) = 20160127122843` But i get this:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the datatype of your field named 'data' ?

Comment: What is value of dateTimeString?

Comment: Which RDBMS (product and version)? You should **never** rely on culture specific date literals... Use ISO 8601, ODBC or Universal Format [Read this for examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34275965/5089204)

Comment: line.Substring(5, 14) = 20160127122843

Comment: If you are not interested in the time, why not change the `(5,14)` to `(5,8)`? SQL Server at least would cast this implicitly...

Comment: Because i need date and time. 20160127122843 = date 2016 01 27 and time 12 28 43

Comment: With your (wrong) `ParseExact` call, you seem to read the date only. I just added an UPDATE to my answer

Comment: It1s working! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to parse a string like this

```
line.Substring(5, 14) = "20160127122843"
```

with

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "dd/MM/yyyy", null)
```

How should this work? Try this

```
string dateTimeString = line.Substring(5, 8); //just 8 to get the date only
var d = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString , "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

After this do not reconvert the date with `ToString()`. Just pass it to the parameter as typed date.

#### UPDATE

If you need the time, keep the `(5,14)` and try this

```
var d = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString , "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Yes I do This! Thx! You made my day :)

Answer (score 4):

Do not convert your string to `DateTime` and then back to string just for the sake of passing it through SQL parameters. Your column in table *probably*  expects a `DateTime` value and since you are adding it with `AddWithValue` it would consider the value to be string and not `DateTime. Simple leave the parsed`DateTime`object as`DateTime`and then you can use`AddWithValue` like:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
//and while adding paramter
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", date);
```

*(Also use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null` to parse `DateTime`, you could run into issues with cultures where the default separator in `DateTime` is different from `/`)*

One other option is to specify DB type explicitly with `Add` like:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data", SqlDbType.DateTime) {Value = date});
```

Comment: I use It:command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data", SqlDbType.DateTime) {Value = date}); And i get this: You can not convert the string to DATATIME

Comment: @CodeObiect Did you take away the final  `ToString()`? If you pass in the date as typed date no conversion is necessary...

Comment: line.Substring(5, 14) = 20160127122843 and it i must write to SQL.

Comment: @CodeObiect, do not convert date to string. Notice the first line of code in the answer, it is creating a `DateTime` object, not a string. Use that.

Comment: But i want convert string to date.

Comment: @CodeObiect, why do you want to do that ? the error is clearly indicating that your column in table is not string. What is the actual type of column in your table ?

Comment: SQL type column: datetime

Comment: Beacuse as you dont convert I get "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Comment: @Habib I think the problem is not while passing a value but earlier while parsing the string. If OP wants to use `ParseExact` the given string should fit to the given format string. This seems to be the reason for the error...

Comment: When I try (for testing) add to SQL DateTime.Now it work, and write me date and time to SQL table.

Comment: @CodeObiect This is clear because in this case you pass in a valid datetime. You are failing **before** this on parsing your string...

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to ISO-8601 format (yyyy-mm-dd etc) for complete clarity

"MM/dd/yyyy" only works on SQL Server installs that have us-english setting.