# How to convert a string in the format of mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a date stored a string in the form of mm/dd/yyyy that is getting passed into a SQL Server SP for inserting into a DB. How do I get it converted in the format yyyy-mm-dd so that SQL Server will actually insert it correctly into a column with a datetime type? Just keeping it as the string mm/dd/yyyy didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: You could try breaking the string into separate yyyy, mm & dd parts and re-assemble as another string in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: `CAST('MM/DD/YYYY' AS DATE)`

Comment: @bjones Your comment is culture dependant! On my german machine this would break... You might look at my answer...

Comment: @DeanOC, There's no need to use complex string splitting. `CONVERT` will parse this format correctly with the appropriate format number...

Comment: @Amanda_Panda I'm surprised it doesn't do anything. I would either expect it to work or give an error. If you are getting an error let us know and we will tell you what it means. Letting us see your code would also help us to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid culture dependant date formats whenever this is possible.

Look at this:

```
DECLARE @StringDate VARCHAR(100)='06/29/2016';

SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT CAST(@StringDate AS DATE)

/*

Throws an exception!

SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT CAST(@StringDate AS DATE)
*/
```

Read about [TSQL: CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and its formats. Your format is the number 101:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@StringDate,101)
```

Best was to use independant formats [You might read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34275965/5089204)

Comment: Also important to note 'CAST' is implicit while 'CONVERT' is explicit.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers, they really helped!

Answer (score 1):

You may use PARSE() to create DATETIME object from culture-specific format and then convert it to required string:

```
select convert(varchar(20), parse('02/15/2016' as datetime2 using 'en-US'), 20);
```

20 is CONVERT()'s specific code for ODBC's date style (YYYY-mm-dd).

Comment: As you are using `CONVERT` why not call this with the appropriate *101* instead of the extra `PARSE` with the culture "en-US"?

Comment: To avoid language switching and VARCHAR string as result. Or am I missing something?

Comment: *How do I get it converted in the format yyyy-mm-dd so that SQL Server will actually insert it correctly into a column with a datetime type* I take this as such there is no need for a re-convert to a varchar type...

Comment: I've missed that one, my bad! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this here are three:

You can set the [DATEFORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) setting before hand:

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;
INSERT INTO Table1 (DateCol) VALUES ('09/30/2016');
```

Or you can use the [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (DateCol) VALUES (CONVERT(datetime, '09/30/2016', 101))
```

Or lastly you can use the [PARSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316.aspx) function, this is more flexible as it will accept other date formats like 'Friday, 30 September 2016' but is apparently a little slower:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (DateCol) VALUES (PARSE('09/30/2016' as datetime using 'en-US'))
```