# how to using distinct in XML SQL using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, sqlxml

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CD.CASE_NO AS CaseNumber , 
    CE.PROCEEDING_ID AS ProceedingId, 
    PR.AC_STATE_CD AS ForeclosureStatecode, 
    0 AS STATUS, 
    GETDATE() AS CreatedDate, 
    1 AS CreatedBy, 
    GETDATE() AS ModifiedDate, 
    1 AS ModifiedBy,
            (
            select * from TBL_PROPERTY FOR XML PATH('T')
            )
            from TBL_CASE_DETAIL CD WITH(NOLOCK)
                    INNER JOIN TBL_AUCTION_DETAIL AD WITH(NOLOCK) ON AD.CASE_DETAIL_ID = CD.CASE_DETAIL_ID
                    LEFT JOIN TBL_AUCTION_PROPERTY_MAPPING TAPM WITH(NOLOCK) ON TAPM.AUCTION_ID = AD.AUCTION_ID
                    LEFT JOIN TBL_PROPERTY PR WITH(NOLOCK) ON PR.PROPERTY_ID = TAPM.PROPERTY_ID
                    LEFT JOIN TBL_AUCTION_PROCEEDING_MAPPING APM WITH(NOLOCK) ON APM.AUCTION_ID = AD.AUCTION_ID

    FOR XML PATH('Foreclosure')
```

Hi Guys, This is my modified code to get a distinct result. but now property part cannot display properly..

This is the result I get it. suppose open another tab for property lets say have 3 property.. so in 1 tab of foreclosure,inside foreclosure have 3 property data, then close foreclose tab..
https://gyazo.com/8a54690c88df3e9bb0dd7ff916c6f86c
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this right, the only thing you have to add is `,TYPE`. Otherwise your inner `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH()` is filled i as text with all forbidden characters escaped...

Try:

```
(
    select * from TBL_PROPERTY FOR XML PATH('T'),TYPE
)
```

Comment: `The xml data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.`

Comment: Yes, that is true, sorry, did not see the `DISTINCT` before... Try without the `DISTINCT`, what happens?

Comment: If have not using `DISTINCT` my record will be repeat 4 times. coz I have 4 records of property.. but I have 2 record of case only..

Comment: https://gyazo.com/2765221aedcf7ccc601c47e1456b8193 suppose have 3 records property.. I have 2 record cases only.. because of property have 4 record so looping 4 times. 1 cases got 3 property, and others 1 case got 1 property

Comment: @KHLIM, but your sub-select calls the entire `TBL_Property`? You bind this table with `LEFT JOIN` in your main select, and call it independantly again **but without any filter!!!** in your sub-select? There's something wrong with your concept...

Comment: Dear @Shnugo: I edit the code joining all table. i did tried using inner join all table but I get wrong result.. I should using left join on this scenario.

Comment: Dear @KHLIM, your edit did not help at all! You just placed more of your code... All of this is irrelevant for the problem, you try to solve... I ask you a last time to provide **sample data** and **expected output**. Set up a **minimal working example** one can use with **copy'n'paste** to reproduce your issue. Otherwise I cannot help you, sorry...

Comment: https://gyazo.com/d8e1187ae7d16ad6749534f6b01a814b
This is I expected result.. but still have 4 result repeated.

Comment: Please go back to the last question and look at my answer. See the way I used `DECLARE @SomeName TABLE(...)` to create dummy tables. See the way I filled them with **sample data**. And then try to reproduce your issue with a small set. Paste this into your question and I'll help you... Your pictures tell me nothing... One thing for sure: The sub-select `select * from TBL_PROPERTY FOR XML PATH('T')` will bring back **the entire table's content**!

Comment: @KHLIM it is very kind of you to say *Thank you so much*, but it would be even kinder to use your right to vote and accept. This is the way to say thank you on SO. Happy Coding!